# Have different thickness and colour for each line in a mdframed box

Tags: mdframed

I want to have a different thickness and color for each of the left line, right line, top line, and bottom line of my mdframe box. How can I achieve that? I am new to LaTeX, really appreciate any help!

Comment: This should be possible with `tcolorbox` as well.

Comment: While this is possible, it would require a complete rewrite of the frame-drawing mechanisms (across a number of platforms: default, PStricks and TikZ). In short, this seems like a lot of work. What's the eventual use-case for this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I simply wanted to design my box better. For example, I want the bottom line to be gray instead of black to indicate the thing following are related to the theorem\proposition (eg. a proof). And the other lines should be black to indicate a separation.